# Active users are changing

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

i have a web application. It has about 25-30 webforms and i publish it with iis on network to users. My problem is "a" user logged on and using application then "b" user is logging in and suddenly "a" user becomes "b" user. How can i solve this?

I tried session and get & set methods for user id but still changing users on network.

this is login page,

```
        cn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id, sifre,aktif from Kullanici where id='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and sifre='" + TextBox2.Text + "' and aktif='1'", cn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string login = TextBox1.Text;
        string pwd = TextBox2.Text;
        bool bayrak = false;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            bayrak = true;
            if ((dr["id"].ToString() == login) && (dr["sifre"].ToString() == pwd) && (dr["aktif"].ToString() == "1"))
            {
                Session["id"] = login;

                Response.Redirect("~/WebForm2.aspx");
            }

        }
```

and this is webform2 code

```
        WebForm1 form1 = new WebForm1();

        kullanici = Session["id"].ToString();

        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {



            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand komutad = new SqlCommand("select ad from kullanici where id='" + kullanici + "'", cn);
            SqlCommand komutsoyad = new SqlCommand("select soyad from kullanici where id='" + kullanici + "'", cn);
            SqlCommand komutadmin = new SqlCommand("select admin from kullanici where id='" + kullanici + "'", cn);
            try{
                name = komutad.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            surname = komutsoyad.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            admin = komutadmin.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
        catch
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx");
        }
            DateTime tarih = DateTime.Today;

            Label1.Text = tarih.ToString().Substring(0, 10) + " --- Welcome " + name + " " + surname;
            cn.Close();

            if (admin == "0" && TreeView1.Nodes.Count == 4)
            {
                TreeView1.Nodes.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }
```

name and surname becomes the last login user on every user.

Comment: Are you using a static variable for the user?

Comment: yes all variables are static

Comment: That's the problem! A static variable in a web application contains the same value for every user.

Comment: i remove static variables and use session but still same problem on network.

Comment: Strange. Show your code otherwise nobody can help you out here.

Comment: its my code. It is working when i start project on visual studio but problem is on network.

Comment: Any global.asax event handler for session ?

Comment: no, i dont know global.asax event handler

Comment: @newusereser how `kullanici` variable is declared?

Comment: @king.code it is public variable, public string kullanici, name, surname, admin;

Comment: @Amit how can i do global.asax events for different user logins?

Comment: You dont have to do it there but just checking if you have anything in Session_Start event of Global.asax. Also, are you doing above test in separate browser session or side by side tabs in browser?

Comment: side by side tabs in the same browser still not working but yes if i use another browser it works, i just create global.asax file and do anything then it solved. So why is not working on side by side tabs in the same browser?

Answer (score 1):

Dont Use Static Variable in Web Application  http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/avoid-static-variables-in-asp-net/

Comment: Check your Database that you are taking the userName based on userId or whatever. And Check for ApplicationState .Basically check those things which share common memory like static variables ApplicationState.Look your code carefully you will get the answer.